# building singularity image for python script in centOS linux

Tags: singularity-container

I am trying to build singularity image in `centOS linux`. to do so I have make the following Singularity.recipe:

```
Bootstrap: yum
OSVersion: 7
MirrorURL: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-%{OSVERSION}/%{OSVERSION}/os/x86_64/
Include: yum

%post
        yum -y install epel-release
        yum -y install python34

%file
        QC.py /

%runscript
    python3 /QC.py
```

and then I used this command to build the image:

```
sudo singularity build test.simg Singularity.recipe
```

but I gave this error:

```
FATAL:   Unable to build from Singularity.recipe: while parsing definition: Singularity.recipe: invalid section(s) specified: file
```

do you know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, `%file` is not a valid section name. The [correct section name](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/definition_files.html#files) is `%files`.